# Retorno JSON de API do Google

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

Faço uma requisição a uma API do Google (API Web Service), no qual me retorna uma JSON (Matriz)... Meu problema é ao tentar extrair dados que são Arrays dentro de Arrays... Como os dados do campo "Photos", segue um pedaço do retorno 
JSON.

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.870775,
               "lng" : 151.199025
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/travel_agent-71.png",
         "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
         "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 270,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAF-LjFR1ZV93eawe1cU_3QNMCNmaGkowY7CnOf-kcNmPhNnPEG9W979jOuJJ1sGr75rhD5hqKzjD8vbMbSsRnq_Ni3ZIGfY6hKWmsOf3qHKJInkm4h55lzvLAXJVc-Rr4kI9O1tmIblblUpg2oqoq8RIQRMQJhFsTr5s9haxQ07EQHxoUO0ICubVFGYfJiMUPor1GnIWb5i8",
               "width" : 519
            }
         ],
```

Dados da primeira camada eu consigo trabalhar normalmente com um for();

```
for(x=0; x < data.results.length; x++){                    
   Vname = data.results[x].name;
}
```

O problema esta na próxima camada de informações:

```
Vref_foto = data.results[x].photos[0].photo_reference; ??? ASSIM NÃO FUNCIONA...

Vref_foto = data.results[x].photos.photo_reference; - NEM ASSIM

Vref_foto = data.results[x].photos[0][0]; - NEM ASSIM
```

Obs.: Utilizo uma requisição AJAX.

Usando ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    types: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+location+'&radius='+radius+'&name='+name+'&key=AIzaLFTH9jIMt975505wuN_89kccy9r',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#coluna_busca_retorno").html("Carregando..."); //Carregando
    },
    error: function (request, status, erro){
        $("#coluna_busca_retorno").html('Ops... Ocorreu algum problema</br>'+status+' : ');
        //Erro
        $("#coluna_busca_retorno").append(request + "-" + status + "-" + erro);
        $("#coluna_busca_retorno").append("sem conexao"); //Erro
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.results[0].name); //FUNCIONA!!!
    }
});
```

Comment: Na verdade estou tentando obter os dados no javascript, que não executa com a falha de syntax, mas também recebo ela no php, vou fazer o teste com var_dump

Comment: alterei o post com mais exemplos

Comment: `data` é o retorno de uma chamada AJAX, e você está tentando manipular no PHP? Não vai dar certo assim...

Comment: está se referindo ao "for" que eu postei? Ele é javascript, as vezes declaro variáveis com $ no javascript também... Todo o post é manipulado no javascript, coloquei a tag php por engano, desculpe!!! Vou alterar...

Comment: Desculpe, ja alterei, é que uso nos dois na verdade, mas em questão é javascript!!!

Comment: Continuo sem a resposta desta questão... :(

Comment: @Rodrigo a tua pergunta é dificil de responder porque não dá para reproduzir. Ou seja o teu problema, como o descreveste funciona normalmente (https://jsfiddle.net/a9x4m8m0/)... podes clarificar a pergunta ou reproduzir o probema?

Comment: @Sergio, muito obrigado, um amigo conseguiu me ajudar a resolver o problema, meu erro estava na manipulação da json no javascript e no php, resolvi com um "foreach" ['photos'] dentro do "foreach" principal da json ['results']. E no javascript funcionou desta maneira também com o "for". Era o correto!!! Vlw

Comment: Ok, então sertia bom colocares uma resposta para a pergunta ficar respondida :)

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
$.ajax({
  types: "get",
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' + location + '&radius=' + radius + '&name=' + name + '&key=AIzaLFTH9jIMt975505wuN_89kccy9r',
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#coluna_busca_retorno").html("Carregando..."); //Carregando
  },
  error: function(request, status, erro) {
    $("#coluna_busca_retorno").html('Ops... Ocorreu algum problema</br>' + status + ' : ');
    //Erro
    $("#coluna_busca_retorno").append(request + "-" + status + "-" + erro);
    $("#coluna_busca_retorno").append("sem conexao"); //Erro
  },
  success: function(data) {
    data.results.forEach(function(result) {
      result.photos.forEach(function(photo) {
        photos.push(photo.photo_reference)
      })
    })

    console.log(photos)
  }
});
```

Obs: o comando `console.log(photos)` irá fazer um log com o array de fotos no console do seu navegador.